# Create wait cursor when launching external app

Tags: c#

This is a neubi question...  I've searched the internet, but evidently I'm not forming the question well.

My winform program launches an external application, let's call it "watchit.exe".
It takes watchit 5-15 seconds from the time it's process starts until it is visible for the user (finally appearing as a task in the task manager).  I don't want the user to get frustrated during this time and keep clicking the button that launches watchit, so I need a wait cursor, or some other indication.

1. There are several custom controls on this form, is there a way to override their individual cursors with a wait cursor ?  Maybe putting text in the form status strip would be better than a wait cursor ?
2. How do I know in my program when Watchit is up and running so I can set the cursor back to default, or change the text in the form status strip ?  I don't want to use a timer to keep checking if Watchit is up and running yet... Not even sure what to check !

I've attempted to use WMI, but it seems to look at processes (or maybe I'm not fully grasping WMI ).

Here is how the process is launched.

```
Process watchIt = new Process();

string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
path = Path.Combine(path, "Watchit.exe");
watchIt.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path, e.ID.ToString());

if (File.Exists(path))
{
    watchIt.Start();  //Starts Watchit, but how do you know when it's 'up' ?
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
}
```

TIA

Comment: Why not just disable the button once its been clicked once?

Comment: I do have code to prevent watchit from being launched multiple times, but the problem is the 'dead time' from when the user clicks until the program is actually available. I need something to distract them while they wait...

Comment: Do you have any control over the Watchit sources, or is this some 3rd-party app that you can't add code to?

Comment: @AresAvatar - I might be able to edit it, I'll have to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually put up a modal dialog with its cursor set to a wait cursor.  You can make it borderless like a splash screen.  Start with it always on top so that it won't appear behind anything, but once it's finished loading set it to normal so the user is not inconvenienced trying to switch apps while waiting.

icemanind provides an excellent solution here if you want to know when to end the wait cursor for a windowed application (Process.WaitForInputIdle).  If it's a console app, or if it has significant setup to do after the main window appears, you will need to use a shared wait handle such as a semaphore or mutex to know when to drop the wait cursor (or use named pipes, but that's more overhead).  I typically name a mutxe with a GUID so that it's unique.

Creation and waiting in your main app:

```
Mutex unlockMutex = new Mutex(false, "MyUniqueName");

try
{
    unlockMutex.WaitOne();
}
catch (AbandonedMutexException ex)
{
    Exception ex2 = ex.InnerException;
}
```

Release in your child app:

```
Mutex unlockMutex = new Mutex(false, "MyUniqueName");

// Release access to unlock mutex
try
{
    unlockMutex.ReleaseMutex();
}
catch (ApplicationException ex)
{
    Exception ex2 = ex.InnerException;
}
```

Comment: not simple stuff for a newbie...  let me study this for a while...  thanks

Comment: You should be able to just copy and paste the code for the wait handle.  If it's the wait dialog that doesn't make sense let me know and I'll add more code.

Comment: I sorta did your answer - I created a pseudo splash screen in the source code for watchIt. I'll give the Mutex thing a try, but how does it work when they are both called 'unlockMutex' and have the same parameter signature ??

Comment: When your main app calls new Mutex, Windows creates a wait handle in a table in the operating system.  When your child app calls new Mutex, Windows gives it the wait handle already created in your main app.  The main app waits on it, like an infinite loop breaking when released, and the child app by calling ReleaseMutex allows the main app to proceed and break out of the waiting.

Comment: So the first unlockMutex goes in my code where I create the process for watchit and the second unlockMutex goes in watchIt somewhere ??

Comment: Exactly.  You create the process, then create and wait on the mutex.  This uses almost no CPU cycles and will use the OS to wait.  In your child app when you are ready you release the same Mutex, which lets your main app proceed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Process.WaitForInputIdle() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d7363e2.aspx). Quoted straight from the MSDN documentation:

```
"This state is useful, for example, when your application needs to wait 
for a starting process to finish creating its main window before the 
application communicates with that window."
```

Comment: +1 for this.  If you don't have a message loop, you'd have to add something like a shared wait handle or named pipes to tell the parent app that you were loaded.

Comment: @icemanind   I looked at the WaitForInputIdle in MSDN, but without program examples, I didn't know how to implement.

Comment: @icemanind - I added   "watchIt.WaitForInputIdle();" following the watchIt.Start(); in my program.   I get a wait cursor for about 4 seconds, but other than that I see no difference.

Comment: @Miffy - You can find [an example here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305369), although they aren't doing exactly what you are doing, it should be the same idea. There is also an example on that site showing how to wait for X number of milliseconds, which you might need to do because AresAvatar is right about his comment. If there is no message loop, this won't work for you. But it sounds like if its got some kind of GUI, then it probably does

Comment: @icemanind - I appreciate your help, but the examples are waiting for an application to close, I'm waiting for one to open.  I finally poked around in the source code for watchIt, and created a pseduo 'splash screen'.  I'm sure there will be hell to pay when the coder for watchIt gets back from vacation next week !!